# knockoutjs in nodejs using .fn extensions in custom modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, npm, node-modules

I am looking at trying to get the `knockout.mapping.merge` library working in node, however I am unable to work out how to achieve extension of ko objects within the module scope as I am unable to extend the underlying ko instance.

So for example in my module I am exporting all the methods relating to the mapping.merge logic, however there is also some logic which extends the base observables to give them the ability to register their merge preferences:

`knockout.observable.fn.withMergeMethod = function(method) {
        this.mergeMethod = method;
        return this;
    }`

knockout in the above scope would be the result from `require("knockout");` but that scope only matches this. I was thinking I could possibly have some sort of init method which passes in the knockout constructor to enrich it in a node environment but was wondering if there was a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like nodejs require only has one instance of the given dependency so if you update it in other defines it will apply those changes to all objects using that require:

[Modules initialization in node.js and persisting their state between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021245/modules-initialization-in-node-js-and-persisting-their-state-between-requests)

Or so says this question, although I am not sure if that is a nice way to go in node, so will wait and see if there are any better answers.